# TensorFlowLite Trying to import a Image Getting erorr: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The size of byte buffer and the shape do not match

Tags: android, image, kotlin, image-processing, tensorflow-lite

I'm Working on the Object detection Using the TensorFlow lite Model in Android, The process is that  we need to convert the selected Image to the Specific buffer size expected the TensorFlow Lite Model,

```
Expected Input:

// Creates inputs for reference.
val inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 24, 24, 1), DataType.FLOAT32)
inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer)
```

```
Input: 

//Resized Grayscale Image
var resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 24, 24, true)

//Converting the Image to Byte Buffer as per Expected
val tImage = TensorImage.fromBitmap(resized)
val byteBuffer = tImage.buffer

//Passing the Input
val inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 24, 24, 1), DataType.FLOAT32)
inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer)
```

```
Error 
erorr:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The size of byte buffer and the shape do not match.
```

Printed Bytebuffer size of image is
[pos=1728 lim=1728 cap=1728]
Expected was
[pos=0 lim=2304 cap=2304]

The issue to match the Bytebuffer of input to the expected input size

```
Got some Reference as 
3*24*24*1=1728
4*24*24*1=2304
```

in this 24* 24 is heigh and width, 1 for the grayscale, Not getting what is the 3 and 4 here may be this will solve my issue.

Expecting to match the  size of the ByteBuffer equalent to the input expected ByteBuffer size

Comment: I don't know what language this is, but it's definitely not one in the [tag:ml] family.

Comment: This an Android application with  Kotlin Language

Comment: Then use the appropriate tags. (And read their descriptions.)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to create the input array (intArray) with size (1, 24, 24, 3) since 3 is for color channels, and the grey scale has 3 color channels (RGB)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response. but the model developed is expecting the grayscale image. so it should be (1,24,24,1). Tried the  intarray(3,24,24,1) even though getting the same error

Comment: To be sure of that, load you .tflite model in netron.app website, after that click in the first node and it will show you what kind of input the model expects, then let me know. Also I don't see anywhere in the code that you have converted the image into grey scale format.

Comment: Thanks for the netron.app it seems to be help full.

Comment: You are welcome, so was the input size like you expected ?